# Error when distributing an IPA over the air with dropbox on 9.2

Tags: ios, iphone

I am able to install ipa using dropbox on 9.2.1 on 5c but not on 6S.

Any idea about that. this is mainfest.plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
<array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/publicul/myapp.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.mysrting.test2</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0.41</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>myapp</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Even i had tried Diwai ..

it was showing **unable to Dowload App**

Any idea.  i had tried with developer and distribution certificates both.

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend generating a new manifest through XCode. I believe that display image and full size image may be required

Comment: then why i am able to install on my iphone 5C with 9.1 not on  iphone 6  9.2 any idea ?

Comment: can you please explain to me

Comment: when you export your IPA through itunes there is a checkbox for generating a new manifest. Go through those steps and make sure your URL's are correct (even capitalization).

Comment: Still not working.. this is working fine on 5C with ios9.1. but not working on iphone 6 with 9.2.1

Comment: Is your Distribution Certificate an AdHoc one ? If so, double check in apple's developer portal that its udid is included in the cert.

Comment: @ThibaudDavid: We dont want to add uuid.

Answer (score 0):

You said in comment you don't want to include UDID of devices on your certificate. I guess you're using AdHoc cert.

If you don't want to provide each udid, you'll need an InHouse certificate, which you can create once you subscribed an [Enterprise Developer Account.](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/enroll/)

Otherwise, you won't be able to install app on devices not included.